# Angular ngModel hooks

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Is there any way to have a hook into the process of setting/retrieving and object to a sub component via the ngModel input. What I'm trying to do is have an instance variable that I pass to a third party component, but before I pass that value to the sub component I want to mutate it. I also want to mutate it when the sub component changes it as well before it reaches the parent component. My use case for this is the ngx Timepicker (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker). The Timepicker accepts a `Date` object but will display the values in the local time zone. I was thinking if there was a way to intercept the value being passed to the Timepicker component I could "fudge" the value to UTC so that the correct values are displayed in the control, then "fix" then when the component attempts to save them back to the model. I'm also open to ideas on how to do this another way.

Example:
`<timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime"></timepicker>`

In this case `myTime` is 03-09-2018 3:20pm EST, but I'd like the control to show 8:20pm.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `[(ngModel)]="mytime"` is shorthand for `[ngModel]="mytime" (ngModelChange)="mytime = $event"`. If you want to do pre/post processing you can split it apart and run methods to process what you need.

```html
<timepicker [ngModel]="preProcessTime(mytime)"
    (ngModelChange)="postProcessTime($event)"></timepicker>
```

With the updates to your component code as the following:

```js
preProcessTime(time: Date): Date {
    // return corrected date object
}

postProcessTime(newTime: Date) {
    // process new time and store as mytime
}
```

Depending on the change detection you have set up, it may be bad to have the `preProcessTime` method. It may be better to hold onto both versions of the time, changing them when needed by code immediately. I don't have enough details to say how often that `preProcessTime` method will be called, just bringing it up as a general note.